# Redcarpet not generating fenced code block with Jekyll

Tags: macos, syntax-highlighting, markdown, jekyll, redcarpet

First off I'm pretty new to Jekyll (and posting on StackOverflow) but I've managed thus far. I had at one point gotten Jekyll to output highlighted code snippets within a fenced block code. Eventually I came back to work on things a while later and noticed the formatting went back to this, without the line numbers and `<a>` tags:

```
<code class="ruby language-ruby" data-lang="ruby">
    <span class="k">def</span> 
    <span class="nf">print_hi</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="nb">name</span><span class="p">)</span>
    <span class="nb">puts</span>
    <span class="s2">"Hi, </span><span class="si">#{</span><span class="nb">name</span><span class="si">}</span><span class="s2">"</span>
    <span class="k">end</span>
    <span class="n">print_hi</span>
    <span class="p">(</span><span class="s1">'Tom'</span><span class="p">)</span>
    <span class="c1">#=&gt; prints 'Hi, Tom' to STDOUT.</span>
</code>
```

Above code is derived from:

````
```ruby
def print_hi(name)
    puts "Hi, #{name}"
end
print_hi('Tom')
#=> prints 'Hi, Tom' to STDOUT.
```
````

My _config.yml:

```
name: Your New Jekyll Site
markdown: redcarpet
pygments: true
permalinks: pretty.
```

One key thing I noticed was that when I run `rvm use system` in the terminal, it serves jekyll with ruby 1.8.7 and let's me know in the terminak (which I assume would be a problem. Alternatively when I use ruby 2.0.0-p247, it just serves it but doesn't tell me which version it's being served with.

Pulling out my hair over this!

Answer (score 2):

Several more night hours and I've beaten the same problem (at least it looks like pretty similar one mentioned by you).

Anyway, for me it was **because of newer version of Python** set up **than** (accourdingly to [this source](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/1181)) **supported by 'Pygments' script**, which is responsible of those blocks processing.

The newest version (for this moment) was **3.3**. After playing and experimenting, reinstalling **2.7.5** version of Python back solved the issue.

*I am a Windows user (I guess, that's not a big difference for Linux one in current situation) and used jekyll server locally.*

---

Additionally... not sure which exactly approach you are using (*I was trying also to install Jekyll on free Heroku hosting dyno as it's mentioned [here](http://mwmanning.com/2011/12/04/Jekyll-on-Heroku-Part-2.html)*), so was experiencing the same problem there (meaning, *the same results*), but after some explorations found out that those guys provide **Python 2.7.4** using by default, and I had to specify the following thing explicitly in _config.yml Jekyll configuration file:

```
markdown: redcarpet
pygments: true
```

for Pygments thing to work.

*(even thought they say that the latest version of Jekyll (as of 1.1) uses redcarpet by default... anyway, that might be related to some deep relationships between all the ruby/python/jekyll settings - I just let it go he he).*